# Need better logic in finding the count of palindrome numbers in the range

Tags: python, palindrome

I have two numbers say A = 10 and B =20.

Now I need to count the palindrome numbers in Range (A,B)

**I tried this:**

```
s = list(map(int,raw_input().split()))
a = s[0]
b = s[1]

l = range(s[0],s[1]+1)
# print "list : ",l

def isNumberPalindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

x = filter(isNumberPalindrome, l)
# print " All Palindorme numbers : ",x
count = len(x)
print count
```

I have **problem of memory exceeding** if A and B are in range of **10^18**.

Can somebody suggest me how to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use xrange ? But with those numbers you'll probably need to find a better algorithm anyway.

Comment: you probably don't want to do the operation `str(n)` twice in the first place, then you don't need to compare the whole string against its reverse, you just need to compare the first half against the second half

Comment: @JMat Comparing two halves won't work for palindrome numbers with an odd number of digits, e.g. 101.

Comment: @Chris: Round down from both ends (so the middle digit isn't checked.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator instead of calling range().

```
from __future__ import print_function

def isNumberPalindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

a = pow(10, 18)
b = pow(10, 19) + 1

def gen_range(start, end):
    i = long(start)
    while i < end:
        yield i
        i = i + 1

count = 0
for l in gen_range(a, b):
    count += isNumberPalindrome(l)

print(count)
```

Comment: The problem is not in python problem is in the algorithm. If you had 10^18 it would take too long.

Comment: Indeed, although a generator solves the problem with range(), it will be slow when the start and end are very large.

Comment: And btw in python3 `range()` is a generator. For python2 there is `xrange()`.

Comment: I had the same thought and considered xrange before writing the generator, but encountered overflow errors.  OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Answer (score 0):

It is not the whole answer. But consider this:

For range `10^n` to `10^n+1` you can find the number of palindromes in constant time. It is `10^ceil(n/2) - 10^ceil(n/2)-1`. Because (for example) for `n = 6` and range from `10^6` to `10^7` (`1 000 000` - `10 000 000`) number of palindromes is the number of possible numbers from 1000 to 10000 (that represent the first half of original numbers. `4315` is the first half of `4315134` and so on).

So you don't filter numbers but find how many palindromes you can generate in such range.

Comment: What good does this do for us? Do you propose some sort of binary search?

Comment: @EmilVikström No. I am saying that for ranges like `10^n` to `10^n+1` you don't need to check every number.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Good logic